# Error while opening pivx wallet on ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, cryptocurrency, pos

I am new in pivx technologies. I will get the error when opening pivx wallet that

**pivx-qt: /home/ioss/PIVX-master/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:704: typename boost::detail::sp_dereference::type boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = boost::signals2::mutex; typename boost::detail::sp_dereference::type = boost::signals2::mutex&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)**

Please give any idea to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error because ./autogen.sh miss configured something ,to avoid the issue just delete the .yourcoin from home directory and then

```
cd yourcoin/depends 
make
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu # if you are using ubuntu 64 bit
make                                 
make install
```